# how to accelerate a spaceship in a particular direction (Corona SDK)

Tags: math, lua, coronasdk, game-physics

I want to accelerate a player in any angle it is pointing in. I am trying this in corona game engine which provides us inbuilt physics engine. I do know acceleration is the rate of change in velocity and time but how do i apply this in code? also how do i accelerate it in any angle?

here is what i tried:

```
player.angle = 30
player.speed = 20
player.acceleration = 2
print(player.angle)
local scale_x = math.cos(player.angle)
local scale_y = math.sin(player.angle)

local function acceleratePlayer (event)

if(event.phase=="began") then

player.speed = player.speed + player.acceleration

player.velocity_x = player.speed * scale_x
          player.velocity_y = player.speed * scale_y
          player.x = player.x + player.velocity_x
          player.y = player.y + player.velocity_y
    end
end
```

Comment: should the accelerating_angle be similar to the player.angle? or i should convert it in radian value?

Answer (score 0):

As you state, acceleration is the change in velocity and over time. You would write this in code as

```
velocity = velocity + acceleration*deltaTime
```

Here `deltaTime` is the time change from your last velocity update. You're using `deltaTime = 1` in your code above.

To accelerate in any angle, the acceleration needs to have two parameters. Depending on what you want, you could add another `acceleration_angle` *or* define it as `acceleration_x`, `acceleration_y` -- both works and what you choose could depend on what you feel is more intuitive/fits your problem better.

Updating velocity from acceleration that is angle dependent:

```
 // acceleration is relative to player
 velocity_x = velocity_x + acceleration*cos(player.angle + acceleration_angle)*deltaTime;
// acceleration is *not* relative to player
 velocity_x = velocity_x + acceleration*cos(acceleration_angle)*deltaTime;
```

For `y` you would just change the `cos` to a `sin`. If you choose not to do update it using an angle, you would just update each direction independently:

```
velocity_x = velocity_x + acceleration_x*deltaTime;
velocity_y = velocity_y + acceleration_y*deltaTime;
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!, i will try this approach! and update my status